# Can't detect second Monitor DVI Debian Jessie

Tags: debian, intel-graphics

My Pc does not detect the second monitor attached on DVI, in preferences->monitor it show only main monitor.

```
xrandr output:
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1080      0.00* 
   1280x1024      0.00  
   1024x768       0.00  
   800x600        0.00  
   640x480        0.00  

lspci 
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphics (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #1 (rev 31)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SATA controller [AHCI mode] (rev 31)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1d.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #10 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PMC (rev 31)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio (rev 31)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SMBus (rev 31)
01:00.0 PCI bridge: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1083/1085 PCIe to PCI Bridge (rev 04)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)

CPUINFO
processor       : 0
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 94
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700 CPU @ 3.40GHz
stepping        : 3
microcode       : 0x9e
```

The Graphic card should be an Intel 530, any help would be appreciate.

Comment: It's strange that your `xrandr` info doesn't show the actual output names. You do have newest versions of of X, xrandr etc. installed?

Comment: xrandr -v
xrandr program version       1.5.0
Server reports RandR version 1.5

Comment: X Server, X libraries, etc. are all newest version, too? What does `Xorg.log` say about the various outputs?

Comment: here is the xorg.log --->    http://pastebin.com/rxc0s2Hw 

how can i verify the X libraries and server versions? can' find

Comment: Log shows you are using the VESA driver (which can't handle multiple monitors) instead of the intel driver for your card. Check in `dmesg` that the intel framebuffer driver `inteldrmfb` is loaded. Check in `aptitude` (or whatever you prefer to use for packet management) that `xserver-xorg-video-intel` is installed, and that all packages containing `xorg` or `libx` (you'll get a few additional ones that way, but it doesn't matter) are the newest version.

Comment: Also, if you use a kernel older than 4.3.x, do [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/intel_graphics#Skylake_support).

Comment: Added the line in the X11 conf file (I created it) but when i try to install  xserver-xorg-video-intel it says that missed the package dependence xorg-video-abi-18  but I can't install it

Comment: here dmesg output, can't see inteldrmfb ---> http://pastebin.com/zc5KGUw6

Comment: `Linux version 3.16.0-4-amd64` is *definitely* to old for this hardware, upgrade at least to 4.6. (Sid has 4.7, experimental has 4.8).

Comment: Updated to 4.7.0-0.bpo.1-amd64 and solved. Thank you

Comment: @marte3707 To mark questions as solved we accept the answers, not append "SOLVED" to the title. Please request the author of comment that helped you to write it down as an answer, or if he doesn't want to, write it as an answer yourself and accept it, please. Doing so might help someone who will be facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Things to check:

- Version of `xrandr`, the `X` server, and the `X` libraries (package manager).
- The version of the kernel and if the intel framebuffer drm module loads (`dmesg` output).
- The `Xorg.log` to see if the driver loads correctly.

For newer hardware, the first step should be to upgrade all components (kernel for drm driver, packages for X) to the newest version.

Comment: I wrote up the diagnostic steps in a somewhat more generic answer.